# LINQ Query to retrieve data from SOAP Envelope using C#

Tags: c#, linq, web-services, soap

I am trying to invoke a SOAP call against a web service, and retrieve the records. I am able to retrieve the records which is at namespace b . But not able to go further and retrieve from namespace c or d. In the below example I have created a XDocument which is a SOAP envelope. This is calling a method or function from web services. which is generating more than one records. I want display the City and State along with Name .

```
<s:Envelope>
    <s:Header>
        <h:MessageHeader></h:MessageHeader>             
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>

    <a:Name>ABC</a:AccountName>
    <a:Value xmlns:b='http://'>
        <b:Address xmlns:c='http://'>
            <c:City>Mumbai</c:City>
            <c:CountryCode i:nil='true'/>
            <c:County i:nil='true'/>
            <c:StateOrProvinceCode>MH</c:StateOrProvinceCode>
            <c:Street1>120 ABCD</c:Street1>
            <c:Street2 i:nil='true'/>
            <c:ZipOrPostalCode i:nil='true'/>
        </b:Address>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I am trying calling a function to retrieve a client that matched a name. So i have added loop through which i can have a Name,Address of each client in Clients. I am able to retrieve a Name for each client but not able to display City and state. Kindly looking for help.

```
var doc = XDocument.parse(result.content.ReadAsStringAsunc().Result);

//retrieving all client     
var clients = from c in doc.Element(s+"Envelope")
    .Elements(s+"Body")
    .Element(e+"Get_Eesponse")
    .Element(e+"Get_Result")
    .Element(b+"Client")
select new
{
    Name = (string)c.Element(b+"Name"),
    //want to retrieve a city and state
    Address = from p in c.Element(b+"Value") where p.element("city") != null select p
};
clients.Dump(); // I am trying all to display list here
```

Comment: Please post the complete document, not just the "Envelope" element. Also, please show how you define `s`, `e`, `b`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should this:

```
.Element(e+"Get_Eesponse")
```

be this:

```
.Element(e+"Get_Response")
```

and instead of:

```
p.element("city")
```

should it be something like:

```
p.Element(c+"City")
```

Comment: I updated the line as mentioned by you. But getting an error 'Where' not found